# Maven plugin version not specified

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have just noticed that plugin's version is optional in maven. I can still build my module without specifying it. Let's take an example with maven-bundle-plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    ....
</plugin>
```

I have written a simple pom.xml without a parent to try this out, so pluginManagement is not involved. I have also checked the super super pom-4.0.0.xml in maven-model-builder to confirm that maven-bundle-plugin isn't there. This plugin version is not specified anywhere.

How does maven determine which version to take?

Comment: Can you show the full pom file of your example ?

Comment: SSCCE: https://gist.github.com/ceilfors/5840917

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From [Maven 3.x Compatibility Notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-AutomaticPluginVersionResolution):

> #### Automatic Plugin Version Resolution
>
> When a plugin was invoked without an explicit version given in the POM
>   or on the command line, Maven 2.x used to pick the latest version
>   available where the latest version could either be a release or a
>   snapshot. **For the sake of stability, Maven 3.x prefers the latest
>   release version over the latest snapshot version.**
>
> Given the threat of
>   non-reproducible builds imposed by automatic plugin version
>   resolution, this feature is scheduled for removal as far as plugin
>   declarations in the POM are concerned. Users of Maven 3.x will find it
>   output a warning when missing plugin versions are detected to
>   encourage the addition of plugin versions to the POM or one of its
>   parent POMs. The Enforcer rule requirePluginVersions can be used
>   additionally check for missing plugin versions in the POM.

Answer (score 3):

If you check the `maven-metadata.xml` file that is in your remote repository (e.g. Nexus) alongside the plugin artifact, you'll see something like this:

```
<metadata>
    <groupId>com.company.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <versioning>
      <latest>0.3.6</latest>
      <release>0.3.6</release>
      <versions>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <version>0.2</version>
        <version>0.3.0</version>
        <version>0.3.1</version>
        <version>0.3.2</version>
        <version>0.3.4</version>
        <version>0.3.5</version>
        <version>0.3.6</version>
      </versions>
      <lastUpdated>20140414212942</lastUpdated>
    </versioning>
  </metadata>
```

I think Maven may use the `<latest>` value to decide which plugin to download if the version is not specified.

Maven 3.0.x gives warnings for missing plugin versions and says "future versions of Maven may refuse to build malformed POMs like these" or something like that.  You should always specify the plugin versions so your build is reproducible.  Otherwise you can end up with some really hard to find bugs.

Comment: I noticed that. I'm just wondering what sorcery is happening behind the scene. Voted up as it is useful for people reading this.

Comment: Didn't see your updated answer until today! I just found the answer in Maven 3.x compatibility notes, it's using `<release>`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps maven follows to resolve the plugin version. <strike>It is documented as in `Resolving Plugin Versions` section of
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-registry.html</strike>

The documentation seems to have been moved, since 7yrs of this post. It is available at [Maven 3.x Compatibility Notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-AutomaticPluginVersionResolution) as @ceilfors mentioned in his answer.

Comment: The step 3 from here is different: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-resolution.html. One says checkLatest is by default enabled, another says it is by default disabled. Which one is correct? I can't find M2_HOME/conf/plugin-registry.xml file too. I'm using maven 3.0.4.

Comment: The does not wok now

Comment: @Sniper, the broken link is updated. See `ceilfors` answer above.