# Error java: invalid source release 1.8

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea, swingx

I am trying to make a GUI in java using the GUI builder in IntelliJ. I created some objects using the GUI builder and it worked fine, but then when I tried running the main method, I first got the error message:

> lambda expressions not supported at this language level.

I found out that I had to change some of my language level settings in my Project structure which I did (changed it to - 8 Lambdas, type annotations etc.). I changed it both in the overall project settings and in the module settings. But now when I run it, I get another error message:

> Invalid source release: 1.8.

I am not sure what to do now? Is it because I have the wrong version of Java installed or? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Check the list of things in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26009627/2308683

Comment: Yes I did everything they said.. but now my main method wont run.. It just says "Nothing here" :/

Comment: Check this answer for possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888592/errorjava-javactask-source-release-8-requires-target-release-1-8