# lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lambda

I have maven project opened in Eclipse. But when I do clean and install, I get above error.

I changed my build path to use SE 1.8 and my compiler is also configured to use 1.8. You can see that in following screen shots.

[image]

[image]

I am seeing little red crosses in project explorer too. You can see that in following picture.

[image]

I am not sure why maven is using SE 1.7 when I have configured it to use 1.8 in Eclipse.

Comment: Look into your pom.xml. Maybe there is the target version set to java 1.7. If you do not see it, please provide the content of the file

Comment: Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888592/errorjava-javactask-source-release-8-requires-target-release-1-8/30524848#30524848)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to configure maven to use 1.8 compatibility when compiling:

```
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>utf8</encoding>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </build>
```

Comment: It worked!! Thanks. I still have those red crosses in my project explorer and they really bug me.

Comment: I had to do Maven Update and that annoying crosses went away.

Comment: where I can see this file to edit?

Comment: What is the version? I am getting this error when pushing code to heroku.
`'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing.`

Edit: Seems like the correct version is 3.8.1 looking off this link https://maven.apache.org/plugins/. The code build still is crashing but I think that is an unrelated problem